# Grails - RESTful Web service responds with 404 when controller is defined

Tags: rest, grails

I defined a domain model class with a few properties and marked it as a RESTful resource using `@Resource` following the official Grails guide on Web services. Now, when testing the application (using Ruby's RestClient) I can see that things are working fine. However, after defining an associated Controller that overrides `save` method (for creating new resource), I've been getting 404 even on just simple GET requests. I defined some test objects using BootStrap so GET should be working.

My controller code looks like this:

```
class ModelController {

    @Transactional
    def save(Model model) {
        def status = 201
        if (model.validate()) {
            model.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        } else {
            status = 422
        }
        render status:status
    }

}
```

Do I still need to do something with the `UrlMappings.groovy` or is there something wrong with my controller code (all my unit tests for it are passing though)?

#### Update

I have created a sample project to demonstrate what's happening. Please check my [bookstore-demo repository on GitHub](https://github.com/psychopunch/bookstore-demo). In the repository, I've defined 2 tags, `rest-working`, and `rest-not-working`. The first one marks the point where things are still working, and second one, as the name suggests, marks where I've created a controller that causes 404 response. This is pretty much what I've done with my actual project so far, and I'm getting the the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, if you are getting a 404 then it sounds like its not even hitting this Controller. I would open developer console and try capture what URL it is hitting - URL being sent is potentially incorrect. If I am experimenting I tend to put println "1" println "2" and so on between my logics to see where the code is going or did it return it at all meaning it didn't even get there. so maybe if you doubt your code try this tactic between your if statements see which numbers get hit.

Also there is not a lot to go on to try give anything of more useful as feedback, but I would also check out the allowedMethods of this Controller if any defined...

unsure how it is being posted by if you have ..

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
```

try changing it to

```
static allowedMethods = [update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
```

unsure if this is still supported:

```
static allowedMethods = [save:['POST','GET'],update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
```

For all the methods refer to:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html

Comment: I tried adding `allowedMethods` in my controller but it still doesn't work. By developer console, what do you mean? I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct URL because it's working with the version where there's no controller.

Comment: Also, if I define a controller for the Resource, do I have to override all the REST-mapped methods (`index`, `create`, `save`, etc.) for it to work? My impression is that I can override only those I need to add special behavior to, and the rest are covered by marking the domain class with `@Resource`.

Comment: sorry by developer console I mean in firefox it is called web console but that makes no sense since you are not testing via a browser....I tried to download the github project but it looked a bit vanilla could not find any references nor any rest mappings.. maybe I missed something.. this link might be of use : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072635/restful-grails-services-in-3-steps.html. although does not answer how controller definition changes things. I guess I was just curious to see if you giving controller ended up creating obscure URL i.e. double controllers being passed.

Comment: The link is broken; here's the [working link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072635/restful-grails-services-in-3-steps.html). Anyway, I think it's a little outdated as the more recent Grails versions supposedly have made most of the tasks built-in. URL mappings are not even necessary if you just use the `@Resource` annotation on the domain class. Can you describe more details on how I could test for obscure URLs?

Comment: that is if you run Linux - that is packet sniffing lo localhost interface assuming you are running in dev mode i.e. http://localhost:8080/yourapp - then it looks for patterns matching http which should be your rest http calls.... I do understand your point though about the link and what you have said so far..

Comment: sorry I had totally forgot about http://grails.org/plugin/tcpmon - this plugin will do all of above but from within the app.